# How to render elements in drop down using vselect in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a form in vue js with select drop downs, I'm trying to use https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/ this library to execute this, according to the documentation I've to pass an array into this and I'm calling a axios method to get the options of the drop downs. I'm getting the data in following format:

[image: Array of the values]

And with following description:

[image: Fields of my data]

I want to only show the names in the option and get values as ID of that particular row, how can I achieve this.

My code look something like this:  https://jsfiddle.net/eemdjLex/1/

```
<div id="app">
  <v-select multiple :options="model.data"></v-select>
</div>

import vSelect from 'vue-select';

Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
    router: router,
    data () {
        return {
            model: {},
            columns: {},
      }
    }
    methods: {
        fetchIndexData() {
                var vm = this;
                axios.get('/companies').then(response => {
                Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
                Vue.set(vm.$data, 'columns', response.data.columns)
            }
    }
});
```

It is not working proper but you get the idea what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Please show the code you've written to do this.

Comment: @thanksd: please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-select` appears to return the entire option as the value when using `v-model` so I might use a pair of computed values here.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    serverData,
    selected: null
  },
  computed:{
    // serverData is a stand in for your model.data.
    // map over that to build your options
    selectOptions(){
      return this.serverData.map(d => ({label: d.name, value: d.id}))
    },
    // selectedOption is just a short computed to get the id value
    // from whatever option was selected. You could also just use
    // "selected.id" in whatever needs the id instead if needed.
    selectedOption(){
      if (this.selected)
        return this.selected.value
      else
        return null
    }
  }
})
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/Njoqwg?editors=1010).

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Answer (score 1):

The official [select docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) may help you

your v-select component should look like

```
new Vue({
  template: `
     <select v-model="selected">
       <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
         {{ option.text }}
       </option>
     </select>
     <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>`,
  el: 'v-select',
  props: [ 'options' ]
  data: {
    selected: ''
  }
})
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but he's using a custom `v-select` component, not a `select` element.

Comment: That's true. I've already being using as per normal select docs and I know it can be implemented like this but I'm using v-select component

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [README](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) on the GitHub page for vue-select, I'm seeing that you can pass the `<v-select>` component an `options` property as an array of objects with `label` and `value` keys.

I would make a computed property to take your `model.data` and format it this way:

```
computed: {
  options() {
    let data = this.model.data;
    let options = [];

    // do whatever you need to do to format the data to look like this object:
    // options = [{ label: 'foo', value: 1 }, { label: 'bar', value: 2 }]

    return options;
  }
}
```

Then pass this computed property to the `<v-select>` instead:

```
<v-select multiple :options="options"></v-select>
```

Comment: I need to iterate the model.data and store in options?

Comment: yeah, i don't know what your model data looks like, but if it's an array, you'd iterate through it, and for each element, push an object to the `options` array with a `label` and `value` property set to whatever properties of the element you want to be the label and value.